# how to find element containing css in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have code

```
<span data-v-7f335dae class="" style="display: inline; line-height: 1; vertical-align: baseline;">text</span>
```

How can I find the element ?

> data-v-7f335dae

Thank you!!

Comment: You can do it by xpath //span[.='text'] for the text value or //span[@data-v-7f335dae] .

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your code trials and any error message and stack trace? We cannot answer your question without a [repro].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.